# JavaScript Ternary operator : document.body.className = document.body.className != "cls" ? "cls" : "";?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code

```
document.body.className = document.body.className != "cls" ? "cls" : "";
```

I can understand "xx ? xx : xx;", but what is "document.body.className = document.body.className != "cls" \". I don't know how it works;
My idea is: if(document.body.className = cls) return ture, if != return flase.

The complete code

```
<style>
    .cls {
      background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body id="bd">
<input type="button" value="open/close" id="btn"/>
<script>
  my$("btn").onclick = function () {
    document.body.className = document.body.className != "cls" ? "cls" : "";

  };
</script>
```

Comment: If `document.body.className` is `'cls'` then it will remove the class, If it is anything other than `'cls'`it will set it to `'cls'`.

Answer (score 1):

The above code is just regular use of ternary operator. I put `()` on the basis of order of execution of operators.

```
my$("btn").onclick = function () {
    document.body.className = (document.body.className != "cls") ? "cls" : "";

  };
```

Whenever the onclick event is triggered. Following happens.

- If the body doesnot have the class name `"cls"` it changes it to `"cls"`
- If its already `"cls"` its changed to `""`

It is just a way to toggle the `className` b/w `"cls"` and `""`

**Note:** You should never change the `className`of the element directly. It will remove all the other classes. You should `Element.classList.add()` and `Element.classList.remove()` to add and removes classes. However in this particular case you can use `Element.classList.toggle`

```
my$("btn").onclick = function () {
   document.body.classList.toggle('cls');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If `document.body.className` is `'cls'` then it will remove the class, If it is anything other than `'cls'` it will set it to `'cls'`. Simple.